# Opencart, как добавить один и тот же товар в корзину не группируя его по количеству?

Tags: opencart

Всем привет. 
Помогите решить возникшую проблему с опенкартом. 
В опенкарте, при добавлении в корзину один и тот же товар много раз, группируется в корзине по количеству, при условии одинаковых параметров у него. То есть, если у товара не задана, например, ни одна опция и кликая по кнопке купить в карточке товара, допустим 10 раз, этот товар в корзине будет отображаться 1 раз с количество 10. http://prntscr.com/nghb1r

Нужно, что бы при каждом добавлении в корзину одного и того же товара он не группировался по количеству, а добавлялся как новая единица с количеством 1. http://prntscr.com/nghbk8 Использовние опций товара для этого не подойдет.

Использую ocstore 2.3.0.2.3. Подскажите, где копать, что менять как добиться желамого результата?

Comment: А в чём смысл такой кастомизации? А ещё же есть основная корзина, там ведь в результате тоже придётся перепидаливать. А ещё есть письмо клиенту и админу с заказом, а там как? А в личном кабинете зарегистрированного покупателя в истории заказов? А в админке в истории заказов?

Comment: Заказ фотообев с возможностью обрезки фото. И одно и тоже фото может быть обрезано с разными параметрами, но иметь одни и теже опции. Например, 2*1м размер и печать на композите с одной стороны, и тоже фото брезается после так же 2*1м, но другая часть фото и эта уже часть идет на другую сторону. В сумме получается один и тот же товар обрезаный по разному, с однинаковыми параметрами по опциям и не сгрупирован в один

Comment: Тут вам наверное больше подойдут text option

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее, не совсем уловил ход мысли?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все куда проще.

В system/library/cart/cart.php
в функции add()
находим код:

```
if (!$query->row['total']) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT " . DB_PREFIX . "cart SET api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "', customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', recurring_id = '" . (int)$recurring_id . "', `option` = '" . $this->db->escape(json_encode($option)) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$quantity . "', date_added = NOW()");
        } else {
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "cart SET quantity = (quantity + " . (int)$quantity . ") WHERE api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "' AND product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND recurring_id = '" . (int)$recurring_id . "' AND `option` = '" . $this->db->escape(json_encode($option)) . "'");
}
```

и меняем его на этот:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT " . DB_PREFIX . "cart SET api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "', customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', recurring_id = '" . (int)$recurring_id . "', `option` = '" . $this->db->escape(json_encode($option)) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$quantity . "', date_added = NOW()");
```

После все работает на всех уровнях как нужно - корзина, админка, письма админу и покупателю.